# Непонятка с Quasar

Tags: javascript

Осваиваю фреймворк Quasar. Питаюсь сделать аутентификацию через firebase. Создал планиг firebase.js

```
var fireApp = firebase.initializeApp(config)

export default ({ app, router, Vue }) => {
  Vue.prototype.$firebase = fireApp

  fireApp.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    if (!user) {
      router.push({ path: 'login' })
    }
  })
```

Теперь в компоненте Login пытаюсь вызвать окно аутентифткации firebase

```
  methods: {
    signIn () {
      var provider = new this.$firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()
      this.$firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider)
    }
  }
```

Но работать не хочет. 
Вопрос. Можно ли ввобще так делать, всмысле `var provider = new this.$firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()` писать в компоненте или провайдер нужно создавать тоже в плагине на экспорт.

Comment: Что именно работать не хочет? Какие ошибки появляются и как их повторить?

Comment: В консоле [Vue warn]: Error in event handler for "click": "TypeError: this.$firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider is not a constructor"

Comment: Проблема решилась. Дело в том, что я экспортировал в плагине firebase.initializeApp(config), а нужно было сам firebase. Теперь все работает. Всем спасибо